# Bash tool to put an icon on taskbar?

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to create a tiny application on my Ubuntu machine. What I want to do is put to an icon on my taskbar beside the volume, and internet connectivity options. I understand that there is a `notify-send` command in bash that I can use, or even switch to `Qt` but that seems to be an overkill for the problem. Concretely, is there a way to create an icon on Ubuntu taskbar with bash, and change its color or text periodically?

Comment: You can add application launcher. Not sure if it will update instantly or some time later or on next login. It all depends on actual software you're using. As for applet/tray area - unlikely to be possible without separate application.

Comment: `bash` is a shell. It runs external commands. That's its purpose in life. There is also a set of commands built into it, none of which has anything to do with your desktop. If you have a command that can put stuff on your taskbar, `bash` can run it. If you don't, `bash` won't help you.

Comment: I second n.m.. For example the tool notify-send does not exist here. You will be in distro-hell (have to test SUSE, Ubuntu, Fedora...) and in desktop-environment-hell (have to test KDE, GNOME, ...) at the same time. With Qt it will just work.

Comment: Related answer - https://askubuntu.com/questions/952792/how-to-make-alltray-work-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: For those targeting XFCE, check https://docs.xfce.org/panel-plugins/xfce4-genmon-plugin

Answer (score 21):

For a very shell friendly way to quickly get tray apps working use [yad](http://code.google.com/p/yad/) (specifically `yad --notification`). It allows you to dynamically change icons, set click event handlers and build a custom context menu. For example:

```
yad --notification --command='echo hello world' --image=myicon.png
```

Will echo 'hello world' on click. Or:

```
yad --notification --command='echo hello world' --image=myicon.png --listen
```

Will read it's standard input waiting for commands to change icons, change visibility, open menu, trigger action and more.

Comment: But how to make the command output change the icon of the `yad`?

Comment: @FábioRobertoTeodoro, the command for changing the icon would be: `icon:myothericon.png`. See the section "NOTIFICATION" in `man yad`

Comment: Still spot on in 2020, an advanced example can be seen there: https://sanana.kiev.ua/index.php/yad

Answer (score 1):

More advanced example using [yad](https://github.com/v1cont/yad).

Shows how to handle click in the same script and how to change the icon on the click. Also shows how to create a simple update loop and exit cleanly.

```bash
# stop on error (always good practice)
set -e 

# create a FIFO file, used to manage the I/O redirection from shell
PIPE=$(mktemp -u --tmpdir ${0##*/}.XXXXXXXX)
mkfifo $PIPE
export PIPE

# attach a file descriptor to the file
exec 3<> $PIPE

# add handler to manage process shutdown
function on_exit() {
    # send command to yad through pipe
    echo "quit" >&3
    rm -f $PIPE
}
trap on_exit EXIT

function update_icon() {
    exec 3<> $PIPE         # just in case
    echo "icon:/path/to/some/icon" >&3
}
export -f update_icon     

# add handler for tray icon left click
function on_click() {
    exec 3<> $PIPE         # required
    echo "clicked"
    echo "icon:/path/to/icon" >&3
    update_icon
}
export -f on_click

# add handler for right click menu Quit entry function 
on_quit() { 
    # signal to the script that it should end when this file is created
    echo "quit" > ./quit.txt 
    exec 3<> $PIPE # required 
    echo "quit" >&3 
} 
export -f on_quit 

# Use a file to indicate a quit command to the script
# Make sure it is gone before we start the program to avoid immediate exit
rm -f quit.txt 

# create the notification icon with right click menu and Quit option
yad --notification                  \
    --listen                        \
    --image="/path/to/icon"  \
    --text="demo tray icon"   \
    --menu="Quit!bash -c on_quit" \
    --no-middle \
    --command="bash -c on_click" <&3 &

# allow user to end the loop from icon right click Quit menu option
while [ ! -f "quit.txt" ]; do 
    #echo "Press [CTRL+C] to stop.."
    update_icon
    sleep 60
done
# clean up after quit
rm quit.txt
```

Based on:

- https://code.google.com/archive/p/yad/wikis/NotificationIcon.wiki
- https://sourceforge.net/p/yad-dialog/wiki/NotificationIcon/
- https://groups.google.com/g/yad-common/c/DT8q1vJ-yOQ

I'm not a bash expert, so fixes are welcome.

`yad` is available for many distros as a standard package. On Debian for example it can be installed by `apt install yad`.

Comment: I can't edit your answer, so:
It would be better with:
# at the start
rm -f quit.txt
# add handler for right click menu Quit entry
function on_quit() {
    echo "quit" > ./quit.txt
    exec 3<> $PIPE         # required
    echo "quit" >&3
}
export -f on_quit

    --menu="Quit!bash -c on_quit" \
    --no-middle \

# at the loop
while [ ! -f "quit.txt" ]; do

# at the end
rm quit.txt

Comment: I'm not sure why, but when I try to make edits it says: "suggested edit queue is full"

Comment: @poleguy Why it would be better? (Btw you can use `backticks` to format small code snippets (as in markdown))

Comment: I'm sorry, I rushed that comment: it would be better because currently if you middle click on the icon in your example it closes the icon but does not close the script. Also middle clicking to close is not a normal behavior for most taskbar apps, so I added the more usual right click menu with a quit option.

Comment: There are few/no basic examples for yad that can be easily found via google or in the yad documentation. This is the best and most basic I've found, so I thought yours deserved a minor upgrade to look like a proper "hello world" example.

Comment: @poleguy Good point. One small thing I don't like about your commit is the `quit.txt` file it creates. If I understand correctly, it just uses it as some temporary "variable". It would be much better to use a proper temporary file then: `QUIT=$(mktemp -u --tmpdir ${0##*/}.XXXXXXXX_quit)`. Do you agree? If so, can you test it please?

Comment: It is just used as a temporary variable. I see no problem using a proper temporary file, but I don't think it would be "much better." The program will behave the same either way except in strange corner cases.

Comment: @poleguy For example, there can be two such scripts in the same working folder. In this case "global variable" will be shared. Also I think that the script creates the file in the starting working directory (cwd) and not in its own directory where the file is located. In any case any of these directories can be read only, and in this case creation of file will fail.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [alltray](https://linux.die.net/man/1/alltray); maybe it's your solution.

From its website:

> **Description**
>
> With AllTray you can dock any application with no native tray icon (like Evolution, Thunderbird, Terminals) into the system tray. A high-light feature is that a click on the "close" button will minimize back to system tray. It works well with Gnome, KDE, XFCE 4*, Fluxbox* and WindowMaker*. Xmms is supported in particular.
>
> **Options**
>
> These programs follow the usual GNU command line syntax, with long
> options starting with two dashes ('-'). A summary of options is
> included below.
>
> -h --help | Show summary of options.
>
> -v --version | Show version of program.
>
> -d --debug | Show debug messages.
>
> -s --show | Do not hide window after start.
>
> -i --icon | Use a PNG image as an icon.
>
> -l --large_icons | allow large icons (> 24x24).
>
> -st --sticky | visible on all workspaces.
>
> -x --borderless | Remove windows decorations border, title, frame... from parent.
>
> -m --menu | Add entry "menu text:command" to popdown menu.
>
> -t --title | Show title change for  seconds. Probably most usefull for xmms.
>
> -g --geometry | initial position. see man X.

**Installation (command in a terminal)**

***- in Ubuntu:***

```
sudo apt-get install alltray
```

***- in Fedora:***

```
sudo dnf install alltray
```

Cheers

Comment: Alltray is not maintained anymore. Alternative - https://askubuntu.com/questions/952792/how-to-make-alltray-work-on-ubuntu-16-04